# How to merge multiple databases into one

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is there an easy way to combine two SQL Server 2005 databases into a single database? I want to take database 'A' and database 'B' and merge them both entirely into database 'C'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called "data conversion" in the business. It can be a full project in itself, there is no quick and dirty answer for your question.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "merge".  If you have two disjoint sets of tables and want to transfer them into the same database structure, that's not a huge problem.

If you are needing to interleave or transform the data from A and/or B, they way to do it will be completely dependent on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to do this by yourself or are looking for a tool that will help you. If latter is an option, take a look at RedGate's SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare. These tools will let you see the differences between the schemas(SQL Compare), as well as the data in each database(SQL Data Compare). Also, they're free for 14 days and fully functional during that period.

Hope this helps,

Srdjan

Answer (score 0):

Right click the database and click export data, and then follow the wizard. Do the same for the other database.